# External HDD keeps ejecting by itself from MacbookPro 2018

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, external-disk

I have a 2018 Macbook Pro and am trying to connect an [Icydock external HDD](https://www.icydock.com/goods.php?id=189) (in raid 1 configuration). This external HDD connects without any problems to my older 2014 MBP. On the new MBP, it is initially recognised but after a few seconds, I see the "Disk Not Ejected Properly" message. I am connecting using [USB-C Digital AV Multiport Adapter](https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MJ1K2ZM/A/usb-c-digital-av-multiport-adapter?fnode=8b) to a [USB 3 to USB 3 A to B cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/AmazonBasics-USB-3-0-Cable-Feet-Black/dp/B00NH144GK).

Comment: What is the length of the USB 3 to USB 3 A to B cable?

Comment: It looks like about 1m

Comment: If you have US$20, try [this adaptor from Belkin®](https://www.amazon.com/Belkin-F2CU036btBLK-Certified-Compatible-ChromeBook/dp/B00WJSPWRM). A shorter USB3 cable from the Icydock to the Belkin® adaptor may be needed. If you have a known good USB3 cable, can you try that?

Comment: The USB 3 cable I am using works fine for my old MBP, so I would assume that is good?

Comment: But you're not using the Apple dongle on the old MPB, correct?

Comment: You might also want to contact ICYdock to confirm that their device will work on your new system. No reason I can see that it wouldn't work, but you never know.